# Acumatica and Stuck In Transit

Tags: acumatica

We have several instances where serial items are stuck "In Transit". This is likely due to a bug where we are able to perform the first step of a 2 step inventory transfer while the same item is technically still in a production job through the JAMs manufacturing process. But since it's tied up in a job, it's unable to be received on the other end. So the item is then stuck in transit. Even if the actual item can be resolved, the other items on that transfer can't be received as a result either.

Usually when we have issues with warehouse locations, we just do a 1 step transfer to get it to be in the correct warehouse, but there is no option to transfer from "In Transit" to the correct final warehouse.

This is less about the bugs/issues that caused it, and more of a general question about how to force an item out of In Transit and into the correct warehouse.

We are on 2017 r2. Hoping someone has some advice as to how we can rectify these situations (even if we have to go into the db to do so).

Thanks.

Comment: We dealt with a similar case where transfers were programmatically corrupted by doing 1 or 2 step transfers (can't recall which) without specifying the target warehouse. Basically if the operation can't be done from UI it requires developing SQL scripts to correct the data or bring it to a state where it can be manipulated on UI.

Comment: Ok, i figured as much. Do you happen to know what we would need to do to handle it? Do we simply have to adjust the quantity in the inlostserial tables for each of the warehouses? or should we perhaps just do an adjustment through the UI?

Comment: Doing an adjustment through the UI is preferable if at all possible. In our case, it  required lengthy investigations on our side involving 2 business analysts and many  scripts and manual procedures to correct the corrupted data. It really wasn't simple.